# How do I calculate lattice points per unit volume?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

My professor was explaining simple cubic, body centered cubic, and face centered cubic lattices and I didn't quite understand the calculations below:

- Simple Cubic: $8 \cdot 1/8 = 1$ lattice point per unit volume
- Body Centered Cubic: $(8 \cdot 1/8) + 1 = 2$ lattice points per unit volume
- Face Centered Cubic: $(8 \cdot 1/8) + (6 \cdot 1/2) = 4$ lattice points per unit volume

Can someone explain the reasoning behind these values in the equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to imagine a cube with spheres (the atoms) on the corresponding locations. Now you have to look at how much of each of these spheres is inside the cube (please see [Patrick Moloneys answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84037/how-do-i-calculate-lattice-points-per-unit-volume/84039#84039) for very descriptive images).

For **Simple Cubic**: You have spheres on all 8 corners. Because the spheres are on the corners of the cube, only $1/8$ of each sphere is *inside* the cube, while $7/8$ of the sphere are on the outside. Now, you have 8 spheres on the corners, giving you 8 times $1/8$ of a sphere. So there is $8 \cdot 1/8 = 1$ sphere inside the cube.

For **Body Centered Cubic** you have a sphere completely inside the cube additionally to the 8 on the corners ($8 \cdot 1/8$). Now we add the $1$ on the inside, giving you a total of ($8 \cdot 1/8) + 1 = 2$ spheres inside the cube.

**Face Centered Cubic** has the same 8 spheres on the corners ($8 \cdot 1/8$) and an additional sphere on all the faces of the cube. For each of these spheres, only half is inside the cube, while the other half is not. There are 6 faces, giving you $6 \cdot 1/2$ spheres for the faces. Add these to the corner spheres and you get $(8 \cdot 1/8) + (6 \cdot 1/2) = 4$ spheres inside the cube.

Comment: I felt as though this answer was easier to understand, so I marked it as correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Atoms on the corners, edges, and faces of a unit cell are shared by more than one unit cell.

An atom on a face is shared by two unit cells $\implies$ half an atom belongs to each unit cell.

[image: Atom on the face]

An atom on the edge is shared by four unit cells

[image: Atom on the edge]

and an atom on the corner is shared by eight unit cells

[image]

What does this have to do with the equations?

Well lets say we have an sodium atom that is crystallized in a simple cubic unit cell, then there would be an sodium atom on each of the eight corners of the cell. However, only $\frac{1}{8}$ of these atoms can be assigned to a given cell. Hence the *simple cubic structure* is

$$8 \, \text{(corners)} \times \frac{1}{8}=1 \, \text{atom}$$

if sodium formed a body centered cubic structure, there would be two atoms per unit cell (as seen in the top diagram). It isn't shared with an other cells. Therefore the *body-centered cubic structure* is given by

$$8 \, \text{(corners)}\, \times \frac{1}{8} + 1 \, \text{(body)}= 2 \, \text{atoms}$$

now finally if sodium was a face-centered cubic structure the six atoms on the faces of the unit cell would contribute three net sodium atoms, for a total of four atoms per unit cell. Hence the *face-centered cubic structure* is

$$8 \, \text{(corners)} \times \frac{1}{8} + \Big{(}6 \, \text{(faces)} \times \frac{1}{2}\Big{)}= 4 \, \text{atoms} $$

Hope this helps